# Rails: Generate simple_form 3.4.0 with integration of bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, simple-form, bootstrap-sass, simple-form-for

I am new to rails and in order to do the task
I tried the command

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

as was recommended, but end up having errors, which are-

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 1006
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Could not find generator 'simple_form:install'.
Maybe you meant 'integration_test', 'scaffold' or 'active_record:model'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Can anyone help me figure out what has gone wrong and what I must do?

I have installed the gems simple_form(3.4.0) and bootstrap-sass(3.3.7)
using the commands

```
 gem install simple_form
 gem install bootstrap-sass
 bundle install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this two line in gemfile as below...

```
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

then fire command `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `simple_form` and `bootstrap-sass` into your Gemfile before runnign `bundle install`. If the problem persists, please do post your Gemfile for clarification.